# Is it possible to setup a filter in Gmail to delete message older than one month?

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script, google-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Webapp to delete certain Gmail messages older than n days?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26795/webapp-to-delete-certain-gmail-messages-older-than-n-days)

The reason I need that is because I need to subscribe to some open source project mail list and I don't need to archive older messages.

Comment: I've achieved something similar to this, auto schedule gmail deletion for a specific label, just have a look step by step instructions video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IS3IuSWp0I

Answer (score 13):

No, because Gmail filters act when the message is received. You can't get Gmail filters to act on messages at other times.

At best, you'll need a search like this:

`label:bulk before:2011/2/22`

You could probably save a link (and then edit the date) or make yourself a bookmarklet that can dynamically put the date in for you.

But you can't do it with a filter.

Answer (score 8):

Now you can, Gmail added new search operator on 2012.11.14
http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2012/11/search-for-emails-by-size-and-more-in.html

> older_than:1m

Detail: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190

> Similar to older and newer, but allows relative dates using d, m, and
>   y for day, month, and year

Comment: Yes, that's fine for search, but filters act on messages as they come in. The OP is looking for something that happens automatically. A search, no matter how fancy, is something that a person needs to initiate.

Comment: You can create a filter with this search :D

Comment: You can *create* a filter with this search, but it won't ever match anything, since (as @AlE. points out) the filters are only applied when the email first comes in to the mailbox. At least, all the test filters I've created with `older_than` haven't done anything.

Answer (score 3):

You could connect to gmail with an IMAP client (Thunderbird, Outlook, etc), and create a rule from there.  The gmail options don't have an option for this.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Gmail filters (rules) only applies on incoming mails, not mails already in the inbox. You can still do a search and manually clean up your inbox by using a very specific search.

Let's say that all your emails you don't want to keep forever are labeled **Newsletters**.
To display all emails labeled Newsletters that are older than 2 months, use the following search query

*label:Newsletters older_than:2m*

You can replace the older_than parameters to something else like 7d

- d: days
- m: months
- y: years

I guess a Google Apps Script could be able to take care of this, but I don't have experience (yet) on that matter.

Answer (score 1):

I guess You could create a script on google apps that runs everyday and removes older messages from gmail. There's an example on how to access to gmail and create statistics:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/gmail-stats