# How to archive Gmail threads by age and label or category

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, gmail-archive, gmail-categories

I have Gmail filters set up to label and categories incoming mail.  How do I automatically archive my mail when it reaches a predefined age, with different ages defined for each label and category?  For example, I want mail labelled "Personal" archive after one day, and mail categorized as "Updates" after five days.

Answer (score -1):

Gmail does not have this functionality built in, but it can be achieved using a Google script.  Here is a list of such solutions:

- [GMail Archive old messages by label and category](https://github.com/warwickallen/GMail-Archive-old-messages-by-label-and-category) by Warwick Allen.
  This script reads the configuration values from a Google sheet.
- [How to Auto Delete Old Emails In Any Gmail Label](http://www.skipser.com/p/2/p/auto-delete-email-in-any-gmail-label-.html) by Arun.
- [Add the Auto-Sweep Feature of Outlook to Gmail](https://www.labnol.org/internet/gmail-auto-purge/27605/) by Amit Agarwal.
- [How to configure Gmail to automatically delete some emails after certain number of days?](http://2sdd.blogspot.ru/2012/11/how-to-clean-up-gmail-inbox-from-emails.html) by IR.
  This solution was provided as an answer to the Web Applications question [Automated solution to delete certain Gmail messages older than n days](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26795/automated-solution-to-delete-certain-gmail-messages-older-than-n-days)
- [Create time-based Gmail filters with Google Apps Script](https://www.johneday.com/422/time-based-gmail-filters-with-google-apps-script) by John Day.

Comment: An answer that requires the reader to go somewhere else to get the information is not a useful answer. We like our answers to be self-contained.

Comment: I agree with @ale, these links (short of the WebApps post) could all go stale tomorrow.  This is not really very helpful for people consulting this over the long term.  If you could expand on how the second, third, and fifth scripts actually help, this *might* be useful.