# Gmail filter to act on old messages

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I receive frequent email notifications from our home security cameras.  I'm happy when they come in, but after a day or so I'd like them archived to a specific folder (untag Inbox, tag with a specific label).

I'm aware of the older_than:1d search option.  It does not seem to stick when saving search criteria as a filter.  The result filter captures all incoming email, thus I don't see the security alerts in my inbox.

I am aware of this question being asked previously ([Is it possible to setup a filter in Gmail to delete message older than one month?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13744/is-it-possible-to-setup-a-filter-in-gmail-to-delete-message-older-than-one-month)).  This question is nine years old, and since Gmail has changed substantially since I'm hoping there may be new options available.

Another option I've considered is scripting something on my IMAP client, but I prefer things like this happen server-side.

Comment: Have you considered to use Google Apps Script?

Comment: Indeed, a Google Apps Script would be the only way to come back on procced emails and archive them. Something along the lines of https://medium.com/@fw3d/auto-archive-emails-in-gmail-after-2-days-1ebf0e076b1c

Answer (score -1):

I use the multiple inbox settings. You can define a search string such as a label, that would put all those messages/conversations into that "inbox".

I would also change the filter to archive the incoming messages that are found my the filter so none of them clutter the main inbox.